# How can I offline install .NET Core and SDK on Linux (RHEL)?

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, offline, rhel

I have to install .NET Core 2.0 and SDK on a Linux machine ([Red Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) (RHEL) distribution) server, where there isn't *any* Internet connectivity. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I extracted the [.NET Core 2.2 package](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/69937b49-a877-4ced-81e6-286620b390ab/8ab938cf6f5e83b2221630354160ef21/dotnet-sdk-2.2.104-linux-x64.tar.gz) into a directory, `/dotnet`, on Linux [openSUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE) 42.1.

Then in a terminal:

```
sudo ln -sf "/dotnet" "usr/bin/dotnet"

export PATH=/usr/bin/dotnet:$netcorepkgs`
```

Then in the terminal, the `dotnet` command works:

```
dotnet --version
```

Output:

```
2.2.104
```

Answer (score 2):

You can download the binaries for the .NET Core version you are interested at the [All Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all) page. Pick the version you are interested in. Then inside that version, there will be a Linux section, select the "x64 Binaries" link, which will download the `.tar.gz` file you can put on the machine and extract to any directory.

Comment: thanks eric,  I am able to successfully extract binaries to a folder in RHEL. However,        running command 'dotnet' results in the error -    'dotnet: command not found'. should be execute any futher steps after extraction ?                                                                                         
 ~/coreprojects > dotnet
-bash: dotnet: command not found

Comment: after setting the path using   'export PATH=$PATH:$netcorepkgs', 'dotnet' command works only on the directory on which binaries are exported.  I have 2 questions  1. How to set path permanently  2. how to make this installation global ? i.e dotnet command should work from any other directory

Comment: What our installers do to make this permanently on the $PATH is to create a symbolic link between where `dotnet` is installed and `/usr/bin`. You can do this with:
`sudo ln -sf "/path/where/installed/dotnet" "/usr/bin/dotnet"`

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me in [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 7:

Download these packages on a CentOS 7 system that is connected to the Internet by these commands:

```
yumdownloader --destdir=/etc/LinuxRepos/DOTNETSDK2.2.402 dotnet-host-3.0.0-x64.rpm
yumdownloader --destdir=/etc/LinuxRepos/DOTNETSDK2.2.402 dotnet-runtime-deps-2.2.7-rhel.7-x64.rpm4.
yumdownloader --destdir=/etc/LinuxRepos/DOTNETSDK2.2.402 dotnet-runtime-2.2.7-x64.rpm
yumdownloader --destdir=/etc/LinuxRepos/DOTNETSDK2.2.402 aspnetcore-runtime-2.2.7-x64.rpm
yumdownloader --destdir=/etc/LinuxRepos/DOTNETSDK2.2.402 dotnet-sdk-2.2.402-x64.rpm
```

Now you have all of necessary rpm's in the path:

> /etc/LinuxRepos/DOTNETSDK2.2.402

Transfer them to the target offline CentOS system and run these commands (in order) to install SDK 2.2.402:

```
sudo yum localinstall dotnet-host-3.0.0-x64.rpm
sudo yum localinstall dotnet-hostfxr-2.2.7-x64.rpm
sudo yum localinstall dotnet-runtime-deps-2.2.7-rhel.7-x64.rpm4.
sudo yum localinstall dotnet-runtime-2.2.7-x64.rpm
sudo yum localinstall aspnetcore-runtime-2.2.7-x64.rpm
sudo yum localinstall dotnet-sdk-2.2.402-x64.rpm
```

*If any one of them failed due to a dependency then download by yumdownloader and install the related dependency.*

Run `dotnet --version` and enjoy!